# RDLC REPORT How to split data to three table per page. Each table is limit 10 rows only

Tags: report, rdlc

I need to make a report like these:

[image]

But I try

1. Add **Row group** with this expression

   ```
       =Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 3)
   ```
2. Add **Column group** with this expression

   ```
       =Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 3) Mod 3
   ```

   And this is a result is wrong

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, because you have this strict format, your best option is to "flatten" the data before you push it to report, so it comes as 10 columns ( 9 columns of data + 1 column for page number) with 10 rows exactly for each PageNumber.

Your columns would be: **A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, C2, A3, B3, C3, PageNumber**.

Then group your table by PageNumber column and set page break between each instance of the group.